# The exchange in the cup product of two cochains gives rise to a coboundary?

Tags: homology-cohomology

Does the cup product of *two cochains* have the following property?
$$f_m \cup h_n = (-)^{mn} h_n \cup f_m + \text{coboundary}$$
The above is valid if both $f_m$ and $h_n$ are cocycles.